# Statically typed emit events in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I just had a run-time error in a Vue / Typescript application that was caused by the fact that [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) are not typed.

For instance this code compiles fine, but does not work at run-time.

```
  // In component A
  public foo() {
    this.$emit("connect", { username: this.username, password: this.password });
  }
```

```
// Component B
<template>
  ... <ComponentA @connect="onConnect"> ...
</template>
<script lang="ts">
...
  public onConnect(username: string, password: string) {
  ...
```

Is there a way to prevent these errors at compile time? I don't just want the emitter and receiver to have types declared - I want those types to be linked so that I actually get a compiled time error if I get one wrong.

***Edit: To be clear I am not asking how to fix the above error.***

***Edit: To be doubly clear, the error I am talking about is the fact that the type passed to `emit` is not the same as the type expected by the callback. This is not detected at compile time.***

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`vue-typed-emit`](https://github.com/andrewvasilchuk/vue-typed-emit) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new interface for your data, always wrap the emitter and only call your custom `foo` method so the `this.$emit` is abstracted:

*models/User.ts*

```
export interface User {
  name: string
  password: string
}
```

*ComponentA.vue*

```
import { User } from '@/models/User';
...
public foo(user: User) {
  this.$emit("connect", user);
}
```

*ComponentB.vue*

```
import { User } from '@/models/User';
...
public onConnect(user: User) {
  ...
```

Comment: Edited my answer, I don't think Vue 2 supports some kind of typed custom events if you are not using class-component syntax, maybe with upcoming Vue 3 and better typescript support we will see some new patterns.

Comment: I am using class-component syntax. But yeah unfortunately your answer doesn't really work because I can still change `public onConnect()` to have a different parameter type without getting a compile time error. For what it's worth, this sort of type checking *does* work in React. :-/